# Downloading file using HttpResponse throwing error as "body size is too long" for large files (>5MB)

Tags: django, python-3.x, file, amazon-s3, download

I am retrieving file from s3 bucket and returning content as a file as shown below:

```
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")     
object = s3.Object(bucket-name,s3_key)    
text = object.get()['Body']        
response = FileResponse(text)          
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=sample.xls'          
return response
```

But i am getting error as `"body size is too long"` while returning file.

Comment: you want to download file from s3 into your system or you just want to read the content of the file?

Comment: read content and download as sample.xls into my system.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper
from django.http import FileResponse

s3 = boto3.resource("s3")     
object = s3.Object(bucket-name,s3_key)    
text = object.get()['Body']        
FileResponse(FileWrapper(file(filename, 'rb')), content_type='application/x-zip-compressed')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=sample.xls'          
return response
```

This will help you.

Comment: still getting same issue. while downloading in local it is working fine. But when i deployed my project in zappa and then download file there i am getting this issue. Thank you.

Comment: What is `DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` in settings file?

Comment: i haven't used that DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE in my settings

Comment: try: `DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 5242880` increase size according to file size. Put this line in settings file

Comment: tried that but not worked. as my file size is 6.5 MB i have given DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE=20971520 as 20 MB still no use.

Comment: then try streaming data.